# What is the height of a regular polygon?

Tags: geometry, polygons

I have three small circles forming a pyramid.  I would like to centre that group in a square but have spent a couple of hours trying to calculate the height of the pyramid. I just can't seem to get them vertically centred.

Given a square, a large circle filling the square and then three smaller circles forming a pyramid, what is the height from the bottom of the smallest circle to the top of the smallest circle.
https://googledrive.com/host/0BwFQiTKfux0qY1Y2d1hRdndtSEk/so_question.svg
Calc radius of each circle of n circles in a circle: www.had2know.com/academics/inner-circular-ring-radii-formulas-calculator.html
apothem: www.mathopenref.com/apothem.html
Python code I tried to get working [python code](https://googledrive.com/host/0BwFQiTKfux0qY1Y2d1hRdndtSEk/so_question.py)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $r$ is the radius of the blue circles, the the width of the blue figure is $4r$ and the height is $\left(2+\sqrt 3\right)r$. The height of a regular triangle play a role here.
By the way, if you rotate the blue pyramid by $30^\circ$, you can grow them a bit bigger.

Comment: The width is 4r. The triangle from the top of the highest blue circle to the widest part is a 30,60,90 degree with sides of 1, sqrt(3), 2. But the bottom two blue circles go below the widest point so the height is larger than the simple triangle.

Comment: @user2517533, think about the triangle formed by the centres of the small circles. That gives you $\sqrt 3 r$. Then extending up and down from the appropriate centres gives an additional $2r$.

Comment: Thanks this works. Peter's comment helped me visualize the solution.